# How can I change display of visible value in django form?

Tags: python, django

I have Django model from external python library:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(...)
  serial = models.CharField(...)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.name)
...
```

I can't change this model, but I want to display on my form widget with value as
"**Item Name (Item Serial)**"

My form is very simple:

```
# forms.py
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('title', 'item',)
```

```
# models.py

class Inventory(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(...)
  item = models.ForeignKey(to='Item'...)
...
```

Can I change display of visible value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), the form field used for selecting a model, supports overriding `label_from_instance` (see the linked docs).

So, subclass a choice field with that...

```
class ItemChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
   def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.name} ({obj.serial})"
```

... and hook it up to your form:

```
# forms.py
class InventoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    item = ItemChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('title', 'item',)
```