# How to fill dropdown on Django from database?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to fill up a dropdown on a form and the data is from database

forms.py

```
// ERROR: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'ModelChoiceIterator' and 'tuple'

    for x in MyModel.objects.values_list(
            'id',
            'name',
            named=True):
        self.fields['mymodel'].widget.choices += ((x.id, '%s - %s' % (x.id, x.name)),)

// I've tried, but it doesnt work

    for x in MyModel.objects.all():
        self.fields['mymodel'].widget.choices += ((x.id, '%s - %s' % (x.id, x.name)),)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

I am getting the date from database, the problem is, it retrieves an error when append to choices

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in the end? The error message implies `self.fields['mymodel']` is a `ModelChoiceField`, so you already are getting model objects in there.

Comment: I am trying to fill up the dropdown on a form with info from DB, as I said, thanks

Comment: Yes, the dropdown will already be filled with information from the database without you doing anything, since it's a ModelChoiceField.

Comment: If you want to change the visible label for a modelchoicefield, then see my answer from yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635098/how-can-i-change-display-of-visible-value-in-django-form/73635147#73635147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
simple_list = []    
for item in MyModel.objects.all():
    simple_list.append([item.id, f"{item.id} - {item.name}"])

self.fields['mymodel'].widget.choices = simple_list
```

Comment: interesting code, is this happening in the form class initializer?